# Add cookie to client request OkHttp

Tags: android, okhttp

So i started using Okhttp 3 and most of the examples on the web talk about older versions

I need to add a cookie to the OkHttp client requests, how is it done with OkHttp 3?

In my case i simply want to statically add it to client calls without receiving it from the server

Comment: You need to be more precise on what you're trying to do. Maybe some code?

Comment: @TudorLuca I need to send http (get post put) while attaching cookie to the request. in Java for example its done like this:                                             URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com:80");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "name1=value1; name2=value2");
        conn.connect();

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can do this:

```java
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    .cookieJar(new CookieJar() {
        @Override
        public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies) {
        }

        @Override
        public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url) {
            Arrays.asList(createNonPersistentCookie());
        }
    })
    .build();

// ...
    
public static Cookie createNonPersistentCookie() {
    return new Cookie.Builder()
        .domain("publicobject.com")
        .path("/")
        .name("cookie-name")
        .value("cookie-value")
        .httpOnly()
        .secure()
        .build();
}
```

or simply

```java
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    .addInterceptor(chain -> {
        final Request original = chain.request();
        final Request authorized = original.newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Cookie", "cookie-name=cookie-value")
            .build();
        return chain.proceed(authorized);
    })
    .build();
```

I have a feeling that the second suggestion is what you need.

You can find [here](https://github.com/lucamtudor/Realm-RxJava-Sandbox/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ro/tudorluca/realm/sandbox/OkHttpActivity.java) a working example.

Comment: thanks for the help, can you tell me how to construct a okhttp3.Cookie?

Comment: Thanks! do you have an example for using the Cookie builder? also, if i want to set cookie on the domain level and not a specific full url?

Comment: @MichaelA the second solution, with the interceptor, will work regardless of your url.

Comment: Double brace initialization is a bad idea for stack overflow code samples! No reason to show clever code when you can show simple code.

Comment: How can I log the cookie for testing purposes @TudorLuca

Comment: line 9: `Arrays.asList(createNonPersistentCookie());` needs a return statement in method `loadForRequest`

Answer (score 16):

If you need to set a cookie for a single request you can just add the header:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .addHeader("Cookie", "yourcookie")
        .url("http://yoursite.com")
        .build();
```

Otherwise, if you want to read cookies returned by the server and attach them to other requests you will need a `CookieJar`. For Android you can use the [PersistentCookieJar library](https://github.com/franmontiel/PersistentCookieJar) which handles cookies properly and also saves them in the shared preferences:

```
ClearableCookieJar cookieJar = new PersistentCookieJar(new SetCookieCache(), new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(context));

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cookieJar(cookieJar)
                .build();
```

Comment: Tried setting the header but it dont seem to work, on the server side no cookie is received

Comment: Try using addHeader("Cookie", "key=value") ?

Comment: Just tested it and it doesn't work, the server doesn't receive the cookie

Comment: @furiel this is the correct method, your problem should be somewhere else.  :)

Comment: @RiccardoCiovati I use this block with PersistentCookieJar but I can not add to Header or different interceptor to. 

When I add just PCJ its ok but when added new interceptor for headers (Accept, Envoirement etc) CookieJar not working.

do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Kaloglu I don't, sorry. Perhaps it'd be better to post your own question with a code example so that people could reproduce your problem.

Comment: How can I log the cookie for testing purposes? @rciovati

Comment: it works.
try 
.addHeader("Cookie", "cookie-name=cookie-value")

Answer (score 7):

I had the same needs, I made my own library.
You can **force** set cookies like this with OkHttp3CookieHelper on https://github.com/riversun/okhttp3-cookie-helper .

```
    String url = "https://example.com/webapi";

    OkHttp3CookieHelper cookieHelper = new OkHttp3CookieHelper();
    cookieHelper.setCookie(url, "cookie_name", "cookie_value");

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cookieJar(cookieHelper.cookieJar())
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
```

**Gradle**

```
compile 'org.riversun:okhttp3-cookie-helper:1.0.0'
```

**Maven**

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.riversun</groupId>
<artifactId>okhttp3-cookie-helper</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You save the day! Thanks.

Comment: how to add  this cookie to .addHeader()

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way to do this is by adding the cookie to the cookieJar. OkHttp will then automatically add the cookies to the request with an interceptor: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/http/BridgeInterceptor.java

```
cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
JavaNetCookieJar cookieJar = new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager);
// add cookies to cookiejar
cookieJar.saveFromResponse("Cookie", listOfCookiesToAdd);

OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
builder.cookieJar(cookieJar)
```

I didn't actually try this code, but it should work.